# Obtaining structure definitions using man pages

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, network-programming

Is it possible to view structure definitions using man pages the way we can see function definitions in UNIX?

For instance, for network programming, we use a structure called `struct sockaddr_in` . Is there anyway to see how sockaddr_in has been defined in the library using man pages?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If you are using vim, you can use ctags to generate tags of `/usr/include` directory and then jump to tag to view the definition. Otherwise it looks like a good opportunity of an open source project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the function. For example, you can get the definition of `struct sockaddr` by looking at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) of `bind(2)`.

Unfortunately, there's no man page specifically for `struct sockaddr`.

Other ways to get this information would be to search for it the appropriate header files.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at header files is definitely an option. But is there any way to determine the function that contains the particular structure?

Comment: Well, I guess a Google search would be a good way. Another way would be to [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for the structure in your include directory.

Comment: Google search is the best option of all .. lol .. but unfortunately I have to work at times without a live internet connection.

Comment: there is one see my answer, although idk if it wasn't at the time you answered.

Answer (score 7):

For any given header:

```
echo '#include <netinet/in.h>' | gcc -E - | less
```

Which generates of relevant interest:

```
# 225 "/usr/include/netinet/in.h" 3 4
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    sa_family_t sin_family;
    in_port_t sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;


    unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr) -
      (sizeof (unsigned short int)) -
      sizeof (in_port_t) -
      sizeof (struct in_addr)];
  };
```

This can be done using any compiler with a preprocessor option (every C compiler I know of can do this).

Answer (score 2):

man-pages is just a files written by human or generated by wish of human. Usually all related structures is mentioned in man-pages with functions they used with. Sometimes you can find pages for header-files ( [time.h(0p)](http://www.squarebox.co.uk/cgi-squarebox/manServer/usr/share/man/man0p/sys_time.h.0p) ). Sometimes there is pages for a whole libraries ( [libsensors(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libsensors) ). Sometimes there is actual pages for structures ( [XAnyEvent(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xanyevent) ).

You may want to check `apropos` and `whatis`. Sometimes they able to find pages related with what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

And I am not sure you should really care: system calls can be viewed as dealing with and providing abstract data types. For instance, even if `open` returns an integer, it has no sense to increment that integer. For such reasons the [Ocaml Unix](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html) module describes the result of `open` as an abstract `file_descr` type, not as an `int` (which it is really).

In other words, your C or C++ code should ideally not change if `struct sockaddr_in` changed.

Comment: That's true in a sense, but what about functions like [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) where you need to know the structure of `struct sockaddr` and friends in order to make the appropriate connection.

Comment: Then a `grep -rn2 sockaddr /usr/include` is practically enough (if all the development packages -like `libc6-dev` etc...- have been installed).

Answer (score 1):

For any given header:

```
echo '#include <netinet/in.h>' | gcc -E - | less
```

Which generates of relevant interest:

```
# 225 "/usr/include/netinet/in.h" 3 4
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    sa_family_t sin_family;
    in_port_t sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;


    unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr) -
      (sizeof (unsigned short int)) -
      sizeof (in_port_t) -
      sizeof (struct in_addr)];
  };
```

This can be done using any compiler with a preprocessor option (every C compiler I know of can do this). The man page for `sockaddr_in` is [`IP(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but the relevant structure can be found in man page of `ip`, you would've to scroll down a little bit. eg -

`> man 7 ip` yields

```
Address format
       An IP socket address is defined as a combination of an IP interface address and a 16-bit
       port  number.   The basic IP protocol does not supply port numbers, they are implemented
       by higher level protocols like udp(7) and tcp(7).  On raw sockets sin_port is set to the
       IP protocol.

           struct sockaddr_in {
               sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
               in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
               struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
           };

           /* Internet address. */
           struct in_addr {
               uint32_t       s_addr;     /* address in network byte order */
           };
```

just search for related man pages and you'll find variety of information for your reference.